# libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)

Tags: linux, libraries, vpn, pptp

```
Installed:
  glibc-static.x86_64 0:2.12-1.107.el6_4.4                                 glibc-utils.x86_64 0:2.12-1.107.el6_4.4

Dependency Installed:
  fontconfig.x86_64 0:2.8.0-3.el6        freetype.x86_64 0:2.3.11-14.el6_3.1     gd.x86_64 0:2.0.35-11.el6        libX11.x86_64 0:1.5.0-4.el6
  libX11-common.noarch 0:1.5.0-4.el6     libXau.x86_64 0:1.0.6-4.el6             libXpm.x86_64 0:3.5.10-2.el6     libxcb.x86_64 0:1.8.1-1.el6


[root@host728 ~]# rpm -Uvh pptpd-1.3.4-2.fc19.x86_64.rpm
warning: pptpd-1.3.4-2.fc19.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 862acc42: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) is needed by pptpd-1.3.4-2.fc19.x86_64
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit) is needed by pptpd-1.3.4-2.fc19.x86_64

[root@host728 ~]# uname -a
Linux host728.me.net 2.6.32-042stab079.4 #1 SMP Thu Jul 18 18:57:29 MSK 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[root@host728 ~]#
```

What am I missing here?

Do I need a different RPM that is RHEL based?

I am running CentOS 6.x

Comment: You need version 2.14 and have version 2.12 installed.

Comment: The problem occurs when you try to install a fedora package on CentOS. How about that?

Comment: Also, that's not really CentOS. It is part of the CentOS userland installed in an OpenVZ container. What you install will be severely limited, particularly if you want to load kernel modules.

Answer (score 1):

```
glibc-static.x86_64 0:2.12-1.107.el6_4.4
```

That's not the normal glibc, it probably doesn't have a .so in it at all.

Of course, your system wouldn't be running without a libc.so.  Try `whereis libc.so.6`.  And install the plain `glibc.x86_64`.